# Java: Input a number infront of every array-value

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I will keep myself as short as possible. I want to add a number infront of every value I output in the console. So for example I output "M4", but I want it to say "4. M4", if it is the 3rd index value.

I can't seem to figure out how to do it though, any help is appreciated.

Thanks on beforehand,
Victor

```
public String toString() {
    String list = "", res = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
        list += songs[i] + "\n";
        res = "Artist: " + artist + "\n" + "Album: " + getTitle() + "\n" + "Melodier: " + "\n" + list;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `i + 1` give you the number you need?

Comment: It does give me a number that I need, I just dont know how to implement it correctly though :(.

Comment: Your code is not minimal; see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Edit your question and add at a valid class declaration, incl. at least the relevant members (`songs`, `artist`, `title`, `getTitle`). Besides, depending on the length of your `songs` array, you may want to use `StringBuilder`, for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to output res? If yes, this might be a plausible solution (thanks for the hint from @JonK):

```
public String toString() {
    String list = "", res = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
        list += (i+1) + ". " + songs[i] + "\n";
        res = "Artist: " + artist + "\n" + "Album: " + getTitle() + "\n" + "Melodier: " + "\n" + list;
        System.out.println(res);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Unfourtanetly, your method doesn't work. Because what happens there is you would first print all the numbers, i.e:

1.
2.
3.
etc..

Then you would print out my array
Mel 1
MELODI 2
etc

THanks anyways!

Comment: @Marante I modified a bit - is this what you want?